# How can I kill a non-responding app?

Tags: macos

What are all the ways to kill a buggy GUI app?

I can't right-click on its icon in the whatever-its-called bar, or use the top-of-window menu.  The app does not respond to anything, and does nothing but eat more and more memory as times goes on.

In Linux, there's `xkill`.  Is there something similar on OSX?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can access the Force Quit dialog box by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>, or using the Apple Menu (top left corner of the screen) and choosing `Force Quit...`. Select the problem app, and click the Force Quit button.

[image]

You can also kill an app using the command line (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal):

```
killall 'Google Chrome'
```

You can also use the Activity Monitor app (/Applications/Utilities). Select an app and click the Quit button:
[image]
Then, from the dialog that slides down, click `Force Quit`.

Comment: Very comprehensive :)

Comment: Holding ⌥⇧⌘⎋ for a few seconds also quits the frontmost application.

Comment: @Lri Hey, I didn't now abou that one! Cool!

Comment: @Lri Very cool! I will have to keep that one in mind.

Answer (score 9):

Another way from the `Terminal`:

```
ps auxww | grep -i 'google chrome' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill
```

Or to force kill:

```
ps auxww | grep -i 'google chrome' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

This can be helpful if the screen isn't responding or you get Spinning Wheel of Death, but are able to somehow get to the terminal (e.g.: via SSH)

Answer (score 7):

The "kill" command also exists in OS X (check out "man kill"); you can also kill an app using a couple of GUI-based tools:

1. press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>. That brings up a "force quit" menu
2. launch the Activity Monitor application. You can also force-quit an app from there.

Comment: The salient feature of `xkill` is that it will kill the owner of a window in X. I do wish there were such an interface in OS X.

Answer (score 6):

All the ways?  There's always another way   :-)

Sometimes <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> will get focus away from the app so you can talk to the Dock or Finder.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> should bring up the Force Quit dialog box.

If you have/can get to a Terminal window, there's the kill command.

If you have another machine and have enabled remote login, you can ssh in to your machine and issue a kill even if the GUI won't respond at all (and if kill doesn't work there's always `sudo reboot` as a last resort).

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You also have the option of <kbd>⌥</kbd>-right-clicking the icon in the dock, which (after a few seconds, likely) will pop up and have a 'Force Quit' option, which you can use to kill an app.

Answer (score 2):

the command line way, paste the following in your terminal ( example with Chrome ) :

```
 while read -r p; do
     kill -9 $p
 done < <(ps -x | grep "Google Chrome.app" | perl -pi -e 's/^\s*(\d+)\s+.*/$1/g;print')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a leftover from XCode, minimized it to look at the title and it was something like CoreServices... so I did:

```bash
pkill -9 -f CoreServices
```

Comment: Isn't this a rather complicated way of writing `pkill -f -9 CoreServices`? :-)

Comment: Replaced the answer, I use this script with dorian-each sometimes but I will try to use pkill