# Firefox won't respond to force-quit

Tags: macos, firefox, applications

On http://repl.it, I accidentally created an infinite loop in Python 3. I tried to close the tab, but Firefox already stopped responding. It wouldn't respond even after a while, so I force quitted FF. Then, I tried to reopen it, and it bounced for a while. It wouldn't reopen, so I force quitted and reopened again. Now, it is just sitting on my Dock with the little black "open" dot below it. Clicking on the icon does nothing.

How can I fix this? (I hate Safari) I don't mind using Bash/Terminal, if it makes a difference. Also, it would be nice if it didn't reboot all my other apps as well, but if worst comes to worst, this is okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you can try (ordered by "assertiveness"):

- Start with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the Force Quit dialog and see if it's there. If it is, force quit it (sounds like you've already tried this).
- Open Terminal, and run `ps -eaf | grep Firefox`. If Firefox appears in the list (note that there will always be an entry for `grep Firefox`, this is not what you want, the actual Firefox will be listed as something like `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`), note the PID (the second column, a number), and run `kill -9 <PID>`.

If neither of these work, try restarting the Dock (maybe Firefox actually isn't running but the Dock is confused):

- Use the same `ps -eaf | grep Dock`.
- There should be a process called `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock`, note the PID and run `kill <PID>`.
- The Dock should disappear momentarily and then restart.

If all this fails, easiest thing to do is probably just reboot your machine. If the usual shutdown dialog fails, press and hold the power button until the computer powers down.

Comment: With the second test, I got:                                                                          501 56821 56296   0  2:42PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep Firefox
Are any of these right?

Comment: If that's all you got, that means that Firefox isn't running. Try restarting the Dock.

Comment: `ps -eaf | grep Dock`:                                                                                         501   248     1   0 31Jan16 ??         2:26.03 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
  501   300     1   0 31Jan16 ??         0:07.82 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dock.extra.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.dock.extra
  501   456   248   0 31Jan16 ??         1:23.62 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/DashboardClient.app/Contents/MacOS/DashboardClient
  501 56944 56296   0  2:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep Dock

Comment: What is the process id?

Comment: It's the first line (note the path), so the PID is 248.

Comment: It's still not working, I'm going to reboot.

Comment: It won't reboot, saying FF won't quit. BTW, the force-quit dialogue recognized FF as open, but clicking Force Quit wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Press and hold the power button to power the computer off.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22180/how-can-i-kill-a-non-responding-app

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I had this, if you hit command option and escape, you can cut all power to it!!! This is the best way for me atleast, thanks thiugh